# All test methods in a package/solution in MSTest

Tags: mstest

I would like to get list of all Test Methods in unit test project/solution. I am using MSTest framework. I would like to get list of all test methods so that I can write some logic to implement logging of all available tests Vs what is executed and which one is being executed etc.,

I am a 1 year old novice in this field. So please provide the detailed explanation or code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a post on how to do this in Nunit and was able to figure out doing it in MSTest.

var tests = new List ();

```
       var testTypes = from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                       orderby t.Name
                       select t;

       foreach (var type in testTypes)
       {
           var testMethods = from m in type.GetMethods()
                             let attributes = m.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestMethodAttribute), true)
                             where attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0
                             orderby m.Name
                             select m;

           foreach (var method in testMethods)
           {
               tests.Add(method.Name);
           }
       }
```